# Realtime updates from multiple pusher channels

Tags: pusher

I am wondering if it is able to import data from multiple pusher channels.

For one channel you use `var channel = pusher.subscribe('channel_name');`
I've tried `var channel = pusher.subscribe('channel1','channel2');` but that doesn't seem to work.

Looking through the docs I have found nothing about this.
Any help would be gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to subscribe to each channel individually e.g.

```
var channel1 = pusher.subscribe( 'channel1' );
var channel2 = pusher.subscribe( 'channel2' );
```